# Two XML Result passes an NUnit

Tags: xml, nunit-2.5

I have two xml result i need to find them whether they are correct or not.

Code :

```
[TestCase]
    public void InterrogateChangeInCircumstances()
    {
        // Accepting the input as well as the output
        string test = inputInterrogateChangeInCircumstances();
        string output = outputInterrogateChangeInCircumstances();
    //Web Service is getting called.
    var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["request_url"]);
    request.Method = "POST";
    var result = Utils.ProcessRequest(request, test);

    //Determing whether the response is passed or failed.
    result = result.Replace(Environment.NewLine, "").Replace(" ", "");
    output = output.Replace(Environment.NewLine, "").Replace(" ", "");


    if (result.Equals(output))
        Assert.Pass();
    else
        Assert.Fail("result: {0} original: {1}", result, output);
}
```

I don't want to compare the result.equal(output). as both result and output are xml document . I would like to know if i could compare these two xml (Result and output ) are same or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to build your own parsing and validating mechanism for this or use the utility as shared in this answer, which is similar to your query:  [Check if two XML files are the same in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19954062/check-if-two-xml-files-are-the-same-in-c)